# Filtering Java classes in Maven WAR

Tags: class, maven, filtering, maven-war-plugin

I struggling with Java class filtering in a Maven WAR. The Maven compile a lot of Java classes and all of them appear in

```
target/classes
```

and I have packages like these:

```
a/A.class
a/b/B.class
a/b/C.class
```

Up to this point is OK. But what I need is to have a single Java class inside of

```
WEB-INF/classes
```

like this one:

```
a/b/B.class
```

This is the plugin's section from my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
        <webXml>${basedir}/src/main/application/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar,a/A.class,a/b/C.class</packagingExcludes>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/application/WEB-INF</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>jboss-web.xml</include>
                </includes>
                <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/application/META-INF</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>standard-jaxws-endpoint-config.xml</include>
                </includes>
                <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Unfortunately all the classes are packaged into my WAR.

Any hint?

Best regards,
SK

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will filter the classes based on a relative location to the app that is built in the target directory. Which means your class files are stored in WEB-INF/classes at this stage.

Try changing this:

```
<packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar,a/A.class,a/b/C.class
```

To

```
<packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar,WEB-INF/classes/a/A.class,WEB-INF/classes/a/b/C.class
```

Comment: An even smarter way to do it would be: `**/**/a/A.class`

Comment: This modification eliminates the B.class but the /a/b remains there.